# How to view total traffic usage of each user in ocserv

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, traffic, openconnect

I'm using ocserv as VPN server in my company on ubuntu, and I want to view how much traffic each user is using. Users are set in ocpsswd file. Do ocserv have this feature or any library I can use? As I search Google and I'm confused.
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

connect your server with putty and run this command

```
occtl show users
```

this command will return all connected users with IDs
[Result of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK4Wv.png)

then type this command to view particular user stats

occtl id [ID from the above command first colum]

```
occtl id 1662451
```

[result of the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E37i.png)

occtl is built-in command of ocserv

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, as I determined, occtl show id is showing user usage for current session only. Is there a way to see or calculate for a period for example a month? Or any file logging all session info everytime a user disconnects and reconnects?

Comment: I've tested several ways for a lightweight approach. Vnstat is doing great. and Openconnect server is using different interface names VPNS{number}. The problem is that everytime a user connects and opens a session, a new interface name is assigned to him/her. Is there a way to avoid changing interface names per session for each user?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ntopng panel to control and monitor traffic.
Or you can run multiple instances of ocserv on your server and let each user use one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I,ve tried ntopng and seems that most features are premium. Prefer a more lightweight way maybe. Running multiple ocserv for 15 users is so weird.